# ComboBoxTableCell JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have something like this class with ArrayList of LocalDate

```
public class Item {
    private ArrayList<LocalDate> dates;
}
```

And a TableColumn in another class

```
ObservableList<Item> itemObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
TableColumn<Item, LocalDate> datesColumn = new TableColumn<>("Dates");
datesColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new ComboBoxTableCell<>());
```

I figured how to set a cellValueFactory for this column, now i want ComboBoxTableCell to have values from object of Item class. So every ComboBox should have it's own values based on Item object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can @Override the `ComboBoxTableCell`'s `startEdit()` method like this:

```
datesColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new ComboBoxTableCell<Item,LocalDate>(){
      @Override public void startEdit() {
                Item item = (Item)getTableRow().getItem();
                getItems().setAll(item.getDates());
                super.startEdit();
        }
});
```

So you will have the dates in your comboBoxes for each individual row with its Item's dates. You may define a `StringConverter<LocalDate>` for it.

Comment: but then i have an ArrayList<LocalDate> in cellData and my ComboBox will have rows of ArrayLists from every Item object

Comment: Ah I see sorry I was used to using one item in a model and not a list so that is why I pit like that I will edit the asnwer

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't work quite as it supposed to, cause now items duplicate every time edit starts, but i think that i'll figure it out myself :)